PS2EXE exe resulting file won't run
I am running PS2EXE to make an executable out of a very basic script. No internal addresses, no calls to internal resources, just a small script to see if a specific IP/FQDN and port are up, that should work on any network. When I go to run the .exe I get this Error message.

Windows cannot access the specified device, path, or file. you may not have the appropriate permissions to access the item

I've tried making other scripts into .exe, and they also are successful created, but I still get the same error.
I've tried saving to other paths, and checking the security settings to make sure it didn't get created in a way I can't run it. I originally installed 1.0.10, removed that and installed 1.0.13, that didn't work.
I tried using the GUI, that didn't work. I tried creating it so that it would require Admin permissions, but it gets the error before it invokes UAC to ask for admin.
I followed the examples for the command, so it always makes a file, it just doesn't work
PS C:\JmpShare> Invoke-ps2exe AreYouUp.ps1

PS2EXE-GUI v0.5.0.29 by Ingo Karstein, reworked and GUI support by Markus Scholtes

Reading input file C:\JmpShare\AreYouUp.ps1
Compiling file...

Output file C:\JmpShare\AreYouUp.exe written

PS C:\JmpShare> 

For the curious, here's my little script
$site = Read-Host Who are we checking? FQDN or IP, plz  
$port = Read-Host Ok cool, what port?  
test-netconnection $site -port $port  
ping $site  
Read-Host -Prompt "Ta Da! Press Enter to continue"


The issue is likely due to the content of your script. Can you share that? I suspect that this is a dupplicate with: Win-PS2EXE - Respect the location of the resulting executable

I mean, a really really basic script
`$site = Read-Host Who are we checking? FQDN or IP, plz
$port = Read-Host Ok cool, what port?
test-netconnection $site -port $port
ping $site
Read-Host -Prompt "Ta Da! Press Enter to continue"`

Please edit your question and add this to it.

Are you running some antivirus software which is detecting it as suspicious and blocking it?

Added the script in question.
@TessellatingHeckler
no AV that would block it, this is what's recommended for use by Engineering and Security.
